# Checking if a file is open

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

For the life of me I can't see why my coding does not work.  The following coding does give me a message if the file is open in notepad, but it doesn't if the file is open in word or excel?

```
 Dim apps = 0
    Dim Process() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses
    For Each p As Process In Process
        If p.MainWindowTitle.ToString.Contains("test") Then
            If p.ProcessName = "notepad" Then
                MsgBox("test file is open in notepad")
                apps += 1
            ElseIf p.ProcessName = "winword" Then
                MsgBox("test file is open in word")
                apps += 1
            ElseIf p.ProcessName = "excel" Then
                MsgBox("test file is open in excel")
                apps += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If apps = 0 Then
        'run my code
    End If
```

It just doesn't seem to check word and excel but both the following snippets of coding work?

```
   Dim Process2() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("winword")
    For Each p As Process In Process2
        If p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("test") Then
            MsgBox("test file is open in word")
        End If
    Next
```

and

```
   Dim Process2() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("excel")
    For Each p As Process In Process2
        If p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("test") Then
            MsgBox("test file is open in excel")
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: What's with the `.ToString` after `MainWindowTitle` in your first example?

Comment: did you try to debug ?! I reccomend that you do, then you will spot very easily what is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the p.ProcessName is "WINWORD" ->UpperCase
you test for "winword", ->lowercase.

change your tests to

```
if(String.Compare(p.ProcessName, "winword", true))
   .....
```

to ignore the case